# Python - Set intersection not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, intersection

I defined two variables list and tuple which I am trying to find the intersection of. In the one case things work as I expected, but in the 2nd the intersection fails and I would have expected it to pass. Can someone point out the obvious for me?

Bob

```
# Test results in 'Match' as expected
a = ['*']
b = ('*', 'APR', 'Line')
if list(set(a) & set(b)):
    print ('Match')

# Test result DOES NOT result in 'Match' whcih was not expected
a = ['APR, SIGEVENT']
b = ('*', 'APR', 'Line')
if list(set(a) & set(b)):
    print ('Match')
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second example cannot match, because `'APR, SIGEVENT'` is **one** string. Python won't split that string and check for string contents for you.

Set intersections require equality between the elements, containment is not one of the options. In other words, since `'APR' == 'APR, SIGEVENT'` is not true, there is no intersection between the two sets, even though `'APR' in 'APR, SIGEVENT'` *is* true.

You'd have to split out `a` into separate strings:

```
a = ['APR, SIGEVENT']
b = ('*', 'APR', 'Line')
if set(el.strip() for substr in a for el in substr.split(',')).intersection(b):
    # intersection between text in a and elements in b
```

This assumes that you really wanted to test for elements in the comma-separated string(s) in `a` here.

Note that for your intersection tests, it is rather overkill to cast the resulting intersection set back to a list.

Demo:

```
>>> a = ['APR, SIGEVENT']
>>> b = ('*', 'APR', 'Line')
>>> set(el.strip() for substr in a for el in substr.split(',')).intersection(b)
set(['APR'])
```

Comment: Painfully obvious...My apologies.  Thank you